# Publishing field type names for feature

Tags: feature, site-column, elements-xml

I'm creating a SharePoint 2010 feature in VS 2010 to add some custom site columns to a site collection via an elements.xml file.

I can't seem to find the Type attribute values for the publishing specific column types like Publishing Image.  I can find the SharePoint Foundation Type values here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979575.aspx but not the publishing specific ones. Can anyone point me to where these are documented?

Answer (score 1):

You do need to use some extra settings for HTML fields and the like.

So, for a multi-line HTML field is uses something like: Type="HTML" RichTextMode="FullHtml" RichText="TRUE"

Here's one from an old project

```
  <Field Type="HTML"
     ID="{3b3c593c-06d6-4a4d-adc8-90d71a895b05}"
     Name="FieldName"
     DisplayName="Field Display Name"
     Group="My Group"
     RichText="TRUE"
     RichTextMode="ThemeHtml"
     Required="TRUE">
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but here are two popular publishing fields:

Image - user can to pick an existing photo or image
Link - user can pick from a existing page

The below blog has some more but I have not used them.
http://koenvosters.wordpress.com/2010/04/27/available-field-types-in-sharepoint-2010/